# python-flask Nomodule named 'flask_nav'

Tags: python, python-3.x, navigation, flask-restful

Actually I am learning python flask Navigation, I installed all the necessary packages successfully, these are some of the packages,

```
app$ venv/bin/easy_install  flask-restful
app$ venv/bin/easy_install  Flask-bootstrap
app$ venv/bin/easy_install  Flask-Navigation
```

but when I am tring to import

```
   from flask_nav import Nav
         or
   from flask_nav.elements import Navbar, View
```

getting error,

```
>>>from flask_nav import register_renderer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'flask_nav'
```

I am using ubuntu-14.02 and Python 3.4.3. How do i fix this error, any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [`Flask-Navigation`](https://flask-navigation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) documentation, you should be importing `Navigation` and not `Nav`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.navigation import Navigation

app = Flask(__name__)
nav = Navigation(app)
```

You might be confusing `Flask-Navigation` with [`Flask-Nav`](http://pythonhosted.org/flask-nav/index.html) which is installed under the package name `flask-nav`.

From the [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/flask-nav/other-software.html#flask-navigation), here are some differences between `Flask-Nav` to `Flask-Navigation`:

> Flask-Nav owes a some good core ideas to Flask-Navigation, which is
>   about a year older and the first place the author looked before
>   deciding to write Flask-Nav. In defense of the reimplementation.
>   Here are some key differences:
>
> - Flask-Navigation rolls all element types into a single Item class,
>     which serves as label, view and link element. This makes it a little
>     hard to extend.
> - The HTML generation in Flask-Navigation is done inside
>     the package itself, while Flask-Nav uses a more complete, external
>     solution.
> - Navigational structure creation and rendering are separate
>     in Flask-Nav (see Renderer). This allows for more than one way of
>     rendering the same navbar, allowing other packages (such as
>     Flask-Bootstrap) to supply renderers as well.
> - Some technical choices were deemed a little strange and have been avoided ([BoundTypeProperty](https://flask-navigation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#flask.ext.navigation.utils.BoundTypeProperty))
> - While Flask-Navigation uses signals and hooks to
>     regenerate navigation bars on every request, Flask-Nav achieves
>     dynamic behaviour by lazily instantiating naviigation bars when they
>     are needed and at the last possible moment.

Comment: yes, @Forge you correct. i was confused with both packages because of there name, thanks for your link (documentation)

Answer (score 0):

I got answer, along with 
$ flask_virtual/bin/easy_install Flask-Navigation

we  need to install **flask-na**v too to get access of

```
from flask_nav import Nav
from flask_nav.elements import Navbar, View
```

so use **$ venv/bin/easy_install --upgrade  flask-nav**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, only this form of importing worked:

`from flask_navigation import Navigation`

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50696358/7969193